# Table in Header with latex?

Tags: latex

I need to create some work instructions in latex. Is there anyway to get a table in the header of a latex page?

Answer (score 3):

Use the fancyhdr package.
For example:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}{l}Line 1\\Line 2\end{tabular}}
```